# extracting values from JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, rest

from rest service I receive below json respoonse

```
{"code":1,"message":"success","status":"success","users":[{"email":"qqq@aa.aa","name":"qq"},{"email":"dd@dd.dd","name":"dd"},{"email":"cc@vv.vv","name":"cc"},{"email":"qq@qq.qq","name":"qq"},{"email":"qq@qq.qq","name":"qq"}]}
```

When I tried to convert this into JSONObject it throws an error,
this is how I tried to extract the JSON response,

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

The error is thrown from above script. Error is below,

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.example.ej.ziphiotest, PID: 21945
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:408)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:402)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:432)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
    at com.example.ej.ziphiotest.requests.UserRequest$1.onResponse(UserRequest.java:85)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**EDIT:**

This is request:

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("key", params[0])
            .url(URL)
            .build();

    try {
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.code() == 200){
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        restResponse = new RestResponse(jsonObject.getString("status"), jsonObject.getString("code"), jsonObject.getString("message"), null, jsonObject.getJSONArray("users"));
                        onTaskComplete.onTaskComplete(restResponse);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Where I missed. Thank you fro your valuable time

Comment: replace this "jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());"
with "jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);"

Comment: to me it doesn't seem like the json error. Can you post your api calling code

Comment: The error isn't in the conversion to a `JSONObject`, it's streaming the `.body()` from the `response`. Note the error coming from `OkHttp Dispatcher`. It's saying your connection is closed already. You should show more context of your code so we can understand what's happening.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, Then what should I do? OK I'll update

Comment: replace JSONObject with `String JSONString = response.body().string()` and check if the exception persists

Comment: Are you calling `response.body().string();` twice, I mean once for logging it and other for converting to JsonObject and processing it?

Comment: @LonelyCpp YES it's remain. When I'm logged the `JSONString`, it's shows json response I've mentioned above.

Comment: @FirozMemon yes, I'm calling twice.

Comment: @EJChathuranga Do not call response body more than once, since it is read as a stream and not stored in memory Reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240

Comment: @FirozMemon ohh my god, That's is the issue. Why we cannot call it twice, Is there any reason for that.

Comment: @FirozMemon great. bCoz it's asynchronusly excuting I think.

Comment: @EJChathuranga Try storing it in a variable and then using the variable, not the `response.body().string()` code. Because response body can be huge so OkHttp doesn’t store it in memory, it reads it as a stream from network when you need it.

When you read body as a string() OkHttp downloads response body and returns it to you without keeping reference to the string, it can’t be downloaded twice without new request.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I was using `response.body().string()` twice within very short amount of time. AS [@Firoz Memon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6944758/firoz-memon) saying in the comments.

> Try storing it in a variable and then using the variable, not the response.body().string() code. Because response body can be huge so OkHttp doesn’t store it in memory, it reads it as a stream from network when you need it. When you read body as a string() OkHttp downloads response body and returns it to you without keeping reference to the string, it can’t be downloaded twice without new request.

copied from [@Firoz Memon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6944758/firoz-memon) commenting from above.

Original Reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240

Answer (score 0):

First parse the Object then Object array like this way:
Don't try to use response.body.string() directly. Just using like below:

```
ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
String content = responseBody.string();
// Do something with "content" variable
```

Reason:
The the string of body is stored in memory to variable content, so we don't need to care of whether the state is closed.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
    JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
```